# How to get week number per month on Powerbi?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to get that week number per month.

EX) September 1,2023 -> August-5Week

MY DAX CALCULATION: WEEKNUM([Date],2) - WEEKNUM(EOMONTH([Date],-1)+1,2)+1
->  September 1,2023 ->  1

EX) September 1,2023 -> August-5Week

Comment: Can you write here the structure of your calendar table?

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea by finding the difference in week numbers between the current date and the first day of that month. However, your formula has an issue regarding the transition between months.
You should correct your formula to account for the difference between the first day of the current month and the end of the previous month, and then add the week number of the current date.

```
WeekNumberWithinMonth = 
VAR FirstDayOfMonth = DATE(YEAR([Date]), MONTH([Date]), 1)
VAR LastDayOfLastMonth = EOMONTH([Date], -1)
VAR WeekOfFirstDay = WEEKNUM(FirstDayOfMonth, 2)
VAR WeekOfLastDayOfLastMonth = WEEKNUM(LastDayOfLastMonth, 2)
VAR WeekNumberOfDate = WEEKNUM([Date], 2)
RETURN 
IF(WeekOfFirstDay > 1, 
   WeekNumberOfDate + 1 - WeekOfFirstDay, 
   WeekNumberOfDate - WeekOfLastDayOfLastMonth)
```